# Is it possible to set [DesignerSerializationVisibility] attribute on property dynamically?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and
I have the following enum and properties:

```
public enum MoreButtonIcon
{
    Default,
    Calendar,
    Clock
}

[DefaultValue(false)]
public bool UseCustomButtonIcon
{
    get;
    set;
}

public MoreButtonIcon CustomButtonIcon
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

I want the property "**CustomButtonIcon**" to only appear in designer, when "**UseCustomButtonIcon**" is true. Otherwise "**CustomButtonIcon**" should be hidden, or at least disabled.

Is it possbile to set:
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)] 
attribute on property dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you making a custom control. That being that, you can't really do that dynamically, or in other words in designer terms - runtime. But what you can do, is adding a check on your CustomButtonIcon property:

```
    enum MoreButtonIcon
    {
        Default,
        Calendar,
        Clock,
        UNKNOWN
    }

    private MoreButtonIcon _customButtonIcon = MoreButtonIcon.UNKNOWN;
    public MoreButtonIcon CustomButtonIcon
    {
        get => _customButtonIcon;
        set
        {
            _customButtonIcon = UseCustomButtonIcon ? value : MoreButtonIcon.UNKNOWN;
            if (DesignMode) Refresh();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No thats not possible, but you can add validation to your properties:

```
private MoreButtonIcon customButtonIcon;
public MoreButtonIcon CustomButtonIcon
{
  get { return this.customButtonIcon; }
  set
  {
    if(!this.UseCustomButtonIcon)
      throw new Exception("UseCustomButtonIcon is false!");
    this.customButtonIcon = value;
  }
}
```